# which performance will gain if more memory available?

Tags: tensorflow

I got the log:

```
2018-06-18 20:33:24.218811: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:217] Allocator (GPU_1_bfc) ran out of memory trying to allocate 2.27GiB. The caller indicates that this is not a failure, but may mean that there could be performance gains if more memory is available.
```

and my program can still run .
So I doubt which performance could gain if more memory is available?  Training speed, accurancy, or something else?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your GPU lacks memory, but the program still runs, then it means that some optimizations won't take place, or some operations will be run on your CPU instead of the GPU, which will decrease the computation speed of your program.

So, if more memory is available, you'll improve your training and testing speed. The accuracy should not change however.

Comment: Thank you very much.   Another  question, I use `nvidia-smi` command and find there are about 200M memory left(total 12000M)  , why I still get the **out of memory** problem?

Comment: It tried using more than 200M for one operation (that requires 300M for instance). When it found out there was not enough space, it either gave up that operation (if it was just for an internal optimization) or put it all on the CPU. Either way, it did not use the remaining 200M, because it couldn't split that operation into smaller parts.